# Cordova: How to maintain login session in cordova mobile application?

Tags: android, cordova, session

Is it possible to maintain login details throughout the application access when user is logged in to the mobile application, like the way we do it in PHP with session concept?

Is there any way to maintain user access based on information maintained like session for mobile App??

Answer (score 1):

You can store in localStorage the user data, for example in your function "onloginOK(response)" (just an example function that is called when the login is successful)

```
function onLoginOK(responseJSON) {
    localStorage.user = responseJSON.user;
    localStorage.pass = encrypt(responseJSON.pass);
    . . . .
}
```

And now in any point of your app you can access that information.